# Gitlab-CI and gradle: How to run gradlew build for project in directory subfolder

Tags: gradle, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a repository in which I want to separate the source code and documentation a little bit. So my directory structure looks like this:

```
/
- .gitlab-ci.yml
- readme.md
+ doc/
  - doc_files.txt
+ src/
  + server/
    - gradlew
    - source_code.java
```

So from the root of the repo, I need to execute `./src/server/gradlew build` to build the project.

Now I need to trigger gradle build via Gitlab-CI, i.e., I would execute said command exactly. This is what I imagine for my `gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
stages:
  - build

server_build:
  stage: build
  image: gradle:7.5.1-jdk18-alpine
  script:
    - './gradlew build'
```

Anyhow, `gradlew` seems to not like being executed from any other directory and fails with the following:

```
> ./src/server/gradlew build

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Directory '/home/user/git/project' does not contain a Gradle build.

A Gradle build should contain a 'settings.gradle' or 'settings.gradle.kts' file in its root directory. It may also contain a 'build.gradle' or 'build.gradle.kts' file.

//...

BUILD FAILED in 668ms
```

So I tried to set the directory with `-p` and/ or pointing with `-b` directly to the settings.gradle in `src/server/` - anyhow, the I get the following errors:

```
> ./src/server/gradlew -b settings.gradle -p src/server/ build

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'server'.
> Could not open proj generic class cache for build file '/home/user/git/project/src/server/settings.gradle' (/home/user/.gradle/caches/7.5.1/scripts/qpzgz2vuqu1er7i9j90pmbyq).
   > BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '_BuildScript_' Unsupported class file major version 63

// ...

BUILD FAILED in 667ms
```

And, quite obviously, Gitlab-CI fails. So I tried to tell Gitlab-CI to `cd` into the directory `/src/server/` before executing `gradlew` in the `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
cd src/server && ./gradlew build
```

Anyhow, this does not work either and fails like this (output from the runner's job in Gitlab-CI):

```
// ...
$ cd src/server && ./gradlew build
Error: Could not find or load main class org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

How can I tell Gitlab-CI to use gradlew build from the root of the repository given the existing directory structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I actually solved it by stumbling upon the solution by chance. To cut to the chase, I had to re-add the file `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar`, which was not uploaded due to `.gitignore`.

All in all, the `gitlab-ci.yml` looks like this:

```
stages:
  - build

server_build:
  stage: build
  image: gradle:7.5.1-jdk18-alpine
  script:
    - cd src/server
    - ./gradlew build
```

The `gitlab-ci.yml` is located in the root of the repository, the entire Java/Spring Boot-project is located in `/src/server/`. This includes the `gradle.build`, `gradlew`, and so on (specifically: everything you'd get out of the Spring Initializr https://start.spring.io/).

So after all, no path configurations or so were necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Can you export `GRADLE_USER_HOME` in **before_script** of .gitlab-ci.yml file.

```
before_script:
  - export GRADLE_USER_HOME=`pwd`/.gradle
```

You can get reference configuration at https://gist.github.com/daicham/5ac8461b8b49385244aa0977638c3420#file-gitlab-ci-yml

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Sadly, this does not seem to work. Firstly, `'pwd'` is exported as a string (without the quotation marks, too). Secondly, wherever I set the `GRADLE_USER_HOME` to manually, it always fails the pipeline, saying `./gradlew`couldn't be found.

Comment: When you did `So I tried to set the directory with -p and/ or pointing with -b directly to the settings.gradle in src/server/` In the error, it has error `Unsupported class file major version 63` Which shows you are using JDK17  while building and Gradle version > 7.3 support JDK17. So either upgrade Gradle or use JDK11.

Comment: This was an error due to my local configuration. Anyhow, when running with JDK19 or 18 and Gradle 7.5.1 it creates the same problems

Answer (score 0):

You should try setting the setting.gradle file in you root directory and build.gradle in the src/server directory. The using the -p should work fine.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Anyhow, my `/src/server` directory contains a full gradle project while `src/otherimplementation` contains another one. Both projects should be opened and used independently in their IDEs (e.g. IntelliJ). So moving the `gradle.build` to another directory is not going to work. What I need is a solution for Gitlab-CI to cd into the project folders and build the projects there.